# Combine multiple images in Emgu or opencv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have lots of colors ranges need to filter then combine achieved images to get single image contained all those filtered colors. like this:

```
    Image<Gray, Byte> grayscale2 = frame2.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                for (int i = 1; i < colors.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    var color1 = colors[i].Split('-');
                    var color2 = colors[i+1].Split('-');
                   var img = frame2.InRange(new Bgr(double.Parse(color1[0]), 
                                 double.Parse(color1[1]), double.Parse(color1[2])),
                        new Bgr(double.Parse(color2[0]), double.Parse(color2[1]), 
                                 double.Parse(color2[2]))).Convert<Gray, Byte>();            
                }
```

"colors" is an array of RGB saved colors as string.
I am looking for the fastest way to combine (merge) all img in grayscale2.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you want. I made a simple program in opencv in python. AS you have grayscale image you can add this images, but you need to remember this. If in image1 pixel has value 150 and in image2 value  150, final pixel has 255 value. So you have to add them with weight.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


img1= cv.imread('image1.jpg')
img2= cv.imread('image2.jpg')


hsv1 = cv.cvtColor(img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv2 = cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_blue = np.array([110, 50, 50])
upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])

mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv1, lower_blue, upper_blue)
mask2 = cv.inRange(hsv2, lower_blue, upper_blue)

alpha=0.5
beta =0.5
output =cv.addWeighted( mask1, alpha, mask2, beta, 0.0, )

cv.imshow('av1',img1)
cv.imshow('av2',img2)
cv.imshow('av3',mask1)
cv.imshow('av4',mask2)
cv.imshow('av4',output)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this by convert the images to bitmap first then combine them it's very faster:

```
    public static Bitmap CombineBitmap(string[] files)
    {
        //change the location to store the final image.

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(files[0]);

        Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img3);
        g.Clear(SystemColors.AppWorkspace);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
             img = new Bitmap(file);

            img.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
            g.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
            //img3.MakeTransparent(Color.White);

        }


        using (var b = new Bitmap(img3.Width, img3.Height))
        {
            b.SetResolution(img3.HorizontalResolution, img3.VerticalResolution);

            using (var g2 = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            {
                g2.Clear(Color.White);
                g2.DrawImageUnscaled(img3, 0, 0);
            }

            // Now save b as a JPEG like you normally would
            return img3;

        }
```